# Building Gstreamer basic tutorial 1 on Windows 10 with VSCode

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, gcc, gstreamer

I'm trying to build and run the gstreamer tutorials on Windows 10 with gcc using VSCode. It can compile successfully, but when I run it through the debugger in VSCode, no window or video comes up.

Here's the basic-tutorial-1.c

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#endif

int
tutorial_main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GstElement *pipeline;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Build the pipeline */
  pipeline =
      gst_parse_launch
      ("playbin uri=https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm",
      NULL);

  /* Start playing */
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  /* Wait until error or EOS */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
  msg =
      gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
      GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

  /* See next tutorial for proper error message handling/parsing */
  if (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg) == GST_MESSAGE_ERROR) {
    g_error ("An error occurred! Re-run with the GST_DEBUG=*:WARN environment "
        "variable set for more details.");
  }

  /* Free resources */
  gst_message_unref (msg);
  gst_object_unref (bus);
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  return 0;
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if defined(__APPLE__) && TARGET_OS_MAC && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE
  return gst_macos_main (tutorial_main, argc, argv, NULL);
#else
  return tutorial_main (argc, argv);
#endif
}
```

Here's the tasks.json file for the linker and libraries it links up to

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "-IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/libadwaita-1",
                "-IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/gtk-4.0",
                "-IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/pango-1.0",
                "-IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include",
                "-IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/glib-2.0",
                "-IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/glib-2.0/include",
                "-IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/harfbuzz",
                "-IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/freetype2",
                "-IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/libpng16",
                "-IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/fribidi",
                "-IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/cairo",
                "-IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/pixman-1",
                "-IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0",
                "-IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/webp",
                "-IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/graphene-1.0",
                "-IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/graphene-1.0/include",
                "-IC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../include/gstreamer-1.0",
                "${file}",
                "-LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib",
                "-ladwaita-1",
                "-lgtk-4",
                "-lpangowin32-1.0",
                "-lpangocairo-1.0",
                "-lpango-1.0",
                "-lharfbuzz",
                "-lgdk_pixbuf-2.0",
                "-lcairo-gobject",
                "-lcairo",
                "-lgraphene-1.0",
                "-lgio-2.0",
                "-lgobject-2.0",
                "-lglib-2.0",
                "-lgtksourceview-5",
                "-lgstreamer-1.0",
                "-lgstadaptivedemux-1.0",
                "-lgstallocators-1.0",
                "-lgstapp-1.0",
                "-lgstaudio-1.0",
                "-lgstbadaudio-1.0",
                "-lgstbase-1.0",
                "-lgstbasecamerabinsrc-1.0",
                "-lgstcheck-1.0",
                "-lgstcodecparsers-1.0",
                "-lgstcodecs-1.0",
                "-lgstcontroller-1.0",
                "-lgstcuda-1.0",
                "-lgstd3d11-1.0",
                "-lgstfft-1.0",
                "-lgstgl-1.0",
                "-lgstinsertbin-1.0",
                "-lgstisoff-1.0",
                "-lgstmpegts-1.0",
                "-lgstnet-1.0",
                "-lgstpbutils-1.0",
                "-lgstphotography-1.0",
                "-lgstplay-1.0",
                "-lgstplayer-1.0",
                "-lgstriff-1.0",
                "-lgstrtp-1.0",
                "-lgstrtsp-1.0",
                "-lgstsctp-1.0",
                "-lgstsdp-1.0",
                "-lgsttag-1.0",
                "-lgsttranscoder-1.0",
                "-lgsturidownloader-1.0",
                "-lgstvideo-1.0",
                "-lgstvulkan-1.0",
                "-lgstwebrtc-1.0",
                "-lgstwebrtcnice-1.0",
                "-lgthread-2.0",
                "-lintl",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\..\\bin\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

And the c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64",
            "compilerArgs": []
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Also, I have read the [Windows Gstreamer installation guide](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-windows.html?gi-language=c#InstallingonWindows-Run) over and over and over again, but it only describes the installation for MSVC and Visual Studio 2017, not GCC and VSCode. I have set every GCC Gstreamer environmental variables to point to `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`, `C:\msys64\mingw64\lib` and `C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\gstreamer-1.0`, which are the directories installed via MSYS2 for the GCC versions. I have even tried pointing them to the directories that the Gstreamer installer created, which is located on `C:\gstreamer`, but even that made no difference.

In the terminal, I notice it does come up with an error, once it reaches this line of code:

```
  if (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg) == GST_MESSAGE_ERROR) {
    g_error ("An error occurred! Re-run with the GST_DEBUG=*:WARN environment "
        "variable set for more details.");
  }
```

What does it mean when it says to re-run with the GST_DEBUG=*:WARN environment variable? And how do I set it up?

Is there something I'm doing wrong with setting up gstreamer? Now surely there must be something I've done incorrectly if I'm using the GCC version. GTK4 libraries don't have this issue, so why does Gstreamer libraries have this issue? I don't understand...

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!